# Question about balls in urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Suppose there are $n$ balls in an urn, and $r$ of them are red.  I select $m$ balls from this urn at random.  What is the probability that at least $k$ of them are red?

$m$ must be less than $n$, but need not be greater than $k$.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to show us some efforts!

Comment: Wait does that mean the problem is actually easy and I'm just brain farting?  Let me give it a second look then.

Comment: Okay I feel really silly, the answer should be $${m \choose k} \cdot \frac{r}{n} \cdot \frac{r-1}{n-1} \cdot \frac{r-k+1}{n-k+1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that at least $k$ are red balls is equal to the probabilities of exactly $k$ read plus probability of exactly $k+1$ red balls plus...plus the probability of $\min\{m,r\}$ red balls:
$$
p=p_k+p_{k+1}+\cdots+p_{\min\{m,r\}}.
$$
But
$$
p_j=\frac{\displaystyle\binom{r}{j}\binom{n-r}{m-j}}{\displaystyle\binom{n}{m}}.
$$
Thus the sought probability is
$$
p=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k}^{\min\{m,r\}}\binom{r}{j}\binom{n-r}{m-j}}{\displaystyle\binom{n}{m}}.
$$